# get revision number of multiple mercurial checkout in bamboo

Tags: build, mercurial, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm checkin out from 2 mercurial repositories in the same build plan of bamboo and I'd like to know the revision number of each repositories.

Is there any way to get this information?

I configured each checkout operation in a different stage but then using ${bamboo.repository.revision.number} always return the first checkout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I didn't find a way to retrieve this info using bamboo variables, I created a Task that inject a custom variable for each checkout operation:

```
echo myChangeset=`hg id --id` > myRepo.properties
```

Any other option will be appreciated.